# Changing default starting position of #anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a URL with an anchor that is working as it should:

```
site.com/item/id#comment-233
```

When opened, the anchor will be positioned at exactly the top of the page.

How do I change the starting point? Let's say I want it to be `50px` down from the top.

The reason I'm needing this is because I have fixed layers at the top of the page, so the comment is appearing overlapped behind the fixed header `div`.

Just in case, because of cross-browser compliance I prefer a solution that does not involve changing the container of the comment to fixed and positioning top minus the height of the header.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming your `<a>` tag has no content, add a class to it tag with a `position:relative; top:-50px;`

Depending on your document, you my also have to wrap it in an absolute `<div>`

This should be cross-browser compatible if implemented correctly.

**EDIT**

This is the test I've done locally and it works fine in FF 3.6

```
<html>

    <body style='margin:0; padding:0;'>
        <div style='position:fixed; height:50px; background-color:#F00; width:100%'>
        Fixed header
        </div>
        <div style='padding-top:50px'>
            <div style='height:100px; margin-top:10px; background-color:#0F0'><a href='#linkhere'>Go to anchor</a></div>
            <div style='height:100px; margin-top:10px; background-color:#0F0'>Blah</div>
            <div style='height:100px; margin-top:10px; background-color:#0F0'>Blah</div>
            <div style='height:100px; margin-top:10px; background-color:#0F0'>
                <a name='linkhere' style='position:relative; top:-75px;'></a>
            Link here</div>
            <div style='height:100px; margin-top:10px; background-color:#0F0'>Blah</div>
            <div style='height:100px; margin-top:10px; background-color:#0F0'>Blah</div>
            <div style='height:100px; margin-top:10px; background-color:#0F0'>Blah</div>
            <div style='height:100px; margin-top:10px; background-color:#0F0'>Blah</div>
            <div style='height:100px; margin-top:10px; background-color:#0F0'>Blah</div>
            <div style='height:100px; margin-top:10px; background-color:#0F0'>Blah</div>
            <div style='height:100px; margin-top:10px; background-color:#0F0'>Blah</div>
            <div style='height:100px; margin-top:10px; background-color:#0F0'>Blah</div>
            <div style='height:100px; margin-top:10px; background-color:#0F0'>Blah</div>
            <div style='height:100px; margin-top:10px; background-color:#0F0'>Blah</div>
            <div style='height:100px; margin-top:10px; background-color:#0F0'>Blah</div>
            <div style='height:100px; margin-top:10px; background-color:#0F0'>Blah</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works on FF 3.6 but it doesn't work in Safari neither Chrome.

Comment: @Martin Added an &nbsp; in `<a name='linkhere' style='position:relative; top:-75px;'>&nbsp;</a>` and now it works in chrome, ff and safari for me

Comment: And that's it. That space explains all the mess. Thank you Damp!

Comment: @Damp It doesn't work in chrome for me. `<a name='linkhere' style='position:relative; top: -50px; visibility: hidden;'>anything</a>` works for me.

Comment: @gfeezy I just tried the exact code I posted in chrome 25 and it works just fine...

Answer (score 10):

This worked a treat for me, based on the above suggestion:

```
<a name="[my-anchor-name]" class="anchor"></a>

.anchor {
    position:relative;
    top:-30px; /* or whatever value you need */
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
.anchor{
  display: block;
  height: 115px; <!--same height as header-->
  margin-top: -115px; <!--same height as header-->
  visibility: hidden;
}

<span class="anchor"></span>
<div>content...</div>
```

from http://www.pixelflips.com/blog/anchor-links-with-a-fixed-header/

Comment: This response is perfect!

Answer (score 6):

Adding "display: block;" worked out for me:

```
<a name="[my-anchor-name]" class="anchor"></a>

.anchor {
    position:relative;
    top:-50px;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This code works on Firefox, Chrome, IE and probably others too:

```
<a id="comment-3" class="shifted_anchor">&nbsp;</a>
<div>
    ... comment ...
</div>
```

Where this is the stylesheet:

```
a.shifted_anchor {
  position: relative;
  top: -35px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

The key is the `float` attribute: we use it to avoid the extra vertical space caused by `&nbsp;`, which in turn is needed for cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: I like the class name but I'd probably not use `&npsp;` here.

Comment: The `float: left;` is indeed the trick! However, the non-breaking space is not required (at least for modern browsers), and should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

So I combined a couple of the ideas here and came up with one that works well for me and across all browsers. The empty anchors do not seem to work well with webkit browsers, definitely doesn't work on Chrome. Adding a pseudo element to the anchor fixes this without breaking layouts.

```
a.anchor { position: relative; top: - $offsetHeight; visibility: hidden; }
a.anchor:before {
  content:"";
  float: left;
  height: 0px;
}
```

Just replace `$offsetHeight` with whatever you need.