# is it possible to shift an anchor (html)?

Tags: html, anchor

I use anchors on my website. There's a header on every pages and it overlaps the page content.  When I use the anchors, the beginning of the div (where the title and text are) is displayed behind the header (I can see it because it is translucent). So my question is : is there a way to shift down the page when using the anchors to make the beginning of the div correctly displayed ??

edit:

more precisely:

```
[...]

<div id="emails">...</div>

<div id="contacts">...</div>

[...]
```

and I want to shift down the page when I link to #email or #contacts

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you please show some code or maybe screenshots? I'm not quite sure what you're talking about... :)

Comment: I see in my inbox that you answered (Aaaaalright, I got i now ...) but the second post isn't online anymore. Did you have a solution?

Comment: This post explains exactly what I wanted to do ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996330/changing-default-starting-position-of-anchor